# How to stop Tkinter Message widget from resizing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating three  "Message widgets"  but they seem to resize in width and height according to the content inside, is it possible to prevent such thing?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(background = 'Yellow')
root.geometry('500x400')

a = '{}'.format('The Elepthan is Big')
b = '{}'.format('The Bird')
c = '{}'.format('The Lion is big and ferocious, kills any animal')

msg = Message(root, text = a, width=300, justify='left')
msg.config(bg='lightgreen',relief=RIDGE, font=('times', 9), pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
msg.pack()


msg = Message(root, text = b, width=300, justify='left')
msg.config(bg='lightgreen',relief=RIDGE, font=('times', 9), pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
msg.pack()

msg = Message(root, text = c, width=300, justify='left')
msg.config(bg='lightgreen',relief=RIDGE, font=('times', 9), pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
msg.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes its possible. Provide us we a sample of the code you are using to create the message widgets and we can tell you what you are missing to prevent the resizing. It might be that you need to add some weight to your grid.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the issues are you having.

Comment: @BryanOakley  Done,  I want all Message widgets with same width but they resize according to the content – espktro 8 mins ago

Comment: @SierraMountainTech  Done, widgets resize according to their content, I want them all with same width

Comment: I am wondering why you are using `message` instead of a `label` is it to  keep the look of message? One other reason is because according to tkinter: `"""Message widget to display multiline text. Obsolete since Label does it too."""`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech so Label can do the same? I was reading a tutorial from 2005, did not know Label could do the same of displaying multiple lines....           so how it is done with Labels, how to prevent Labels from resizing?

Comment: I have never needed to do multi line with labels. I just copied that right out of the _tkinter library that message is located in. I would have to google it to know for sure.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I managed to fix the problem, by using Labels. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE:

You have a few options here but according to your comment `widgets resize according to their content, I want them all with same width` I will give the example that best fits your need using the `pack()` geometry manager.

for pack at least the simplest option is to do  `pack(fill = BOTH)`

The quickest way to do what you want is to use a frame. The frame will resize to the largest text and the use of `pack(fill = BOTH)` on all your message widgets will expand the smaller ones to the size of the frame that is also the size of the largest widget.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(background = 'Yellow')
root.geometry('500x400')

a = '{}'.format('The Elepthan is Big')
b = '{}'.format('The Bird')
c = '{}'.format('The Lion is big and ferocious, kills any animal')

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

msg = Message(frame, text = a, width=300, justify='left')
msg.config(bg='lightgreen',relief=RIDGE, font=('times', 9), pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
msg.pack(fill=BOTH)


msg = Message(frame, text = b, width=300, justify='left')
msg.config(bg='lightgreen',relief=RIDGE, font=('times', 9), pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
msg.pack(fill=BOTH)

msg = Message(frame, text = c, width=300, justify='left')
msg.config(bg='lightgreen',relief=RIDGE, font=('times', 9), pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
msg.pack(fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what about a fixed width rather than the parent width?   Frame = 400 Message  =  270       ...either with grid or pack, I just need all Message widgets with the same width(270) but not the width of the parent widget(400).

Comment: There are some options. One is to disable grid resizing of the frame so the frame is forced to stay a set width. I know there are other options but I will need to think about it. I will see what I can find.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by finding the width of the longest message and then centering all of them within that length value by using the `Message` widget's `padx` option. Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='Yellow')
root.geometry('500x400')

a = 'The Elepthan is Big'
b = 'The Bird'
c = 'The Lion is big and ferocious, kills any animal'
messages = a, b, c

msgfont = tkFont.Font(family='times', size=9)
maxwidth = max(msgfont.measure(text) for text in messages)  # get pixel width of longest one

for text in messages:
    msg = Message(root, text=text, width=maxwidth, justify='left')
    padx = (maxwidth-msgfont.measure(text)) // 2  # padding needed to center text
    msg.config(bg='lightgreen', relief=RIDGE, font=msgfont, padx=padx, pady=-2, borderwidth=3)
    msg.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just use a frame and the allow everything to resize on its own using `pack(fill=BOTH)`

Comment: @Sierra: Yes, if putting everything inside a frame is acceptable—which depends on the overall design and what else is going on. The method shown in my answer may be more involved, but shows how to control `Message` widgets without doing that (and how to calculate the values needed).

Comment: ty for the explanation :)